# Jquery selector > can't select autofocus attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select elements that have an `autofocus` attribute present. For some reason, my jquery selector `$("[autofocus]")` isn't returning anything.

I imagine this is a simple solution, I just can't see what I'm doing wrong (is it a bug?!).

**Browser:** Chrome - Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)

#### HTML :

```
<input id="a" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" value="a" />
<input id="b" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" value="b" />
<input id="c" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" value="c" />
```

#### Javascript :

```
console.log($("[type=text]").length); // -> 3
console.log($("[autofocus]").length); // -> 0
console.log($("[autofocus=autofocus]").length); // -> 0
```

Why can't I select the `autofocus` attribute?

#### [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fuhiji/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/193/

Comment: It certainly works with `document.querySelector`.

Comment: There's some problem with your HTML. Notice that the first input is missing. And if you inspect the DOM, it shows `="autofocus"` with no attribute name before it.

Comment: It may be worth noting that it is not valid HTML to have multiple elements with `autofocus` attributes. This could possibly lead to side-effects such as not working at all.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the invalid `</input>` after the button.

Comment: Never mind about the first input, that's because of your CSS that hides it.

Comment: It gets rendered as `="autofocus"=""` for me…

Comment: Bug in JsBin then? JsFiddle looks fine. (**JsBin**: `<input id="b" type="text" ="autofocus"="" value="b">`). @ZakariaAcharki - if you post as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @NickGrealy Can you share link to JSBin where you tried `javascript` at Question?

Comment: It seems to be a bug, yes… I can’t seem to produce a working `autofocus` attribute via HTML in JSBin…

Comment: @guest271314 You mean [the link at the bottom of the question](http://jsbin.com/fuhiji/edit?html,js,console,output)?

Comment: Ummm… I found a workaround… `<input autofocus autofocus="autofocus"/>`. Only the first `autofocus` gets removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/193/)**

Your code works just fine as you could see in the example below. the bug come from the JsBin that translate the `autofocus="autofocus"` to `="autofocus"`.

Hope this helps.

```js
var focusFn = function(){
  console.log("inside fn");
  console.log($("[type=text]").length);
  console.log($("[autofocus]").length);
  console.log($("[autofocus=autofocus]").length);
  $("input[type=text]:visible:first").focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="focus" onclick="focusFn()"></input><br/>
<input id="a" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" value="a" /><br/>
<input id="b" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" value="b" /><br/>
<input id="c" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" value="c" /><br/>
```